# (conditional probability) Compute the probability that the first 2 balls selected are black and the third selected ball is white.

Tags: probability

An urn initially contains 6 white and 8 black balls. Each time a ball is selected, its color
is noted. If the selected ball is white, then it is replaced in the urn along with 3 other black balls. If the
selected ball is instead black, then it is replaced along with 2 other white balls. Compute the probability
that the first 2 balls selected are black and the third selected ball is white.

My answer:

$P(B_1B_2W_3)=\frac{{8 \choose 1} {6 \choose 0}}{{14 \choose 1}}\frac{{8 \choose 1} {8 \choose 0}}{{16 \choose 1}}\frac{{8 \choose 0} {10 \choose 1}}{{18 \choose 1}}$

which I think equals 10/63

Is my understanding of this problem correct?

Comment: You are correct.  Nice work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your method works but you have avoided the [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

Start with:

$$P(B_1)=\frac{8}{14}$$

return the black ball and add two white balls to give:

$$P(B_2|B_1)=\frac{8}{16}$$

return the black ball and add two white balls to give:

$$P(W_3|B_1B_2)=\frac{10}{18}$$

$$\begin{align}
P(B_1B_2W_3)&=P(W_3|B_1B_2)P(B_2|B_1)P(B_1)\\
&=\frac{10}{18}\frac{8}{16}\frac{8}{14}\\
&=\frac{10}{63}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please go through the diagram to understand the problem clearly.